# How to fix CouchDB test errors

Tags: couchdb

I installed CouchDB on my local machine, but after I ran the test suite there were some errors. I've attached an image of my CouchDB test suite errors.

[image]

<sub>Click on the image to get a bigger version.</sub>

Comment: Show the full error from your log file.

Comment: You mean the file in /var/log/couchdb/couch.log

Comment: Yes, but only the errors from that file.  You should be able to find the errors you're seeing in Futon in your log file.  They'll have the full details.

Comment: Where do I get only the errors from? My couch.log is too huge

Comment: You look in your log for those errors, you can use `grep` or something.

Comment: Try to Run using Docker, It is more fun.